# How to flatten multiple column and rows in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here's my excel data:

| Main Topic |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sr No | column 1 |  |  |  | column 2 |  |  |  |
| Sr No | sub-col1 | sub-col2 | sub-col3 | sub-col4 | sub-col1 | sub-col2 | sub-col3 | sub-col4 |
| First Topic |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1) Sub Topic-1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 107 | 207 | 307 | 407 | 507 | 607 | 707 | 807 |
| 2 | 108 | 208 | 308 | 408 | 508 | 608 | 708 | 808 |
| 3 | 109 | 209 | 309 | 409 | 509 | 609 | 709 | 809 |
| 4 | 110 | 210 | 310 | 410 | 510 | 610 | 710 | 810 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2) Sub Topic-2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 113 | 213 | 313 | 413 | 513 | 613 | 713 | 813 |
| 2 | 114 | 214 | 314 | 414 | 514 | 614 | 714 | 814 |
| 3 | 115 | 215 | 315 | 415 | 515 | 615 | 715 | 815 |
| 4 | 116 | 216 | 316 | 416 | 516 | 616 | 716 | 816 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Second Topic |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1) Sub Topic-1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 120 | 220 | 320 | 420 | 520 | 620 | 720 | 820 |
| 2 | 121 | 221 | 321 | 421 | 521 | 621 | 721 | 821 |
| 3 | 122 | 222 | 322 | 422 | 522 | 622 | 722 | 822 |
| 4 | 123 | 223 | 323 | 423 | 523 | 623 | 723 | 823 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2) Sub Topic-2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 126 | 226 | 326 | 426 | 526 | 626 | 726 | 826 |
| 2 | 127 | 227 | 327 | 427 | 527 | 627 | 727 | 827 |
| 3 | 128 | 228 | 328 | 428 | 528 | 628 | 728 | 828 |
| 4 | 129 | 229 | 329 | 429 | 529 | 629 | 729 | 829 |

**image1.png**

[image]

Now, I want to change the data (because my data modeling guy said to make it this way before adding to sql) and I don't know how to change it to such dataframe.

The change is shown in below image:

**image2.png**

[image]

P.S. Note: This is dummy data and the length of rows and columns always vary. Any help me appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO: Reposting a question and not fixing what was suggested in the prior post, i.e. not to post screenshots of data, does not help you find a solution. Please do read the guidelines on how to post questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there are multiple very simple tools for generating markdown from an Excel sheet.  Use one and update your question

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes I'll make sure next time.

Comment: @RobRaymond thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is just about being systematic

- as your "data modeller" has correctly identified,  the source data is not fully structured.
- work out your row and column multi-indexes and then it is structured

```
src = """| Main Topic     |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
|----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| Sr No          | column 1 |          |          |          | column 2 |          |          |          |
| Sr No          | sub-col1 | sub-col2 | sub-col3 | sub-col4 | sub-col1 | sub-col2 | sub-col3 | sub-col4 |
| First Topic    |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| 1) Sub Topic-1 |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| 1              | 107      | 207      | 307      | 407      | 507      | 607      | 707      | 807      |
| 2              | 108      | 208      | 308      | 408      | 508      | 608      | 708      | 808      |
| 3              | 109      | 209      | 309      | 409      | 509      | 609      | 709      | 809      |
| 4              | 110      | 210      | 310      | 410      | 510      | 610      | 710      | 810      |
|                |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| 2) Sub Topic-2 |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| 1              | 113      | 213      | 313      | 413      | 513      | 613      | 713      | 813      |
| 2              | 114      | 214      | 314      | 414      | 514      | 614      | 714      | 814      |
| 3              | 115      | 215      | 315      | 415      | 515      | 615      | 715      | 815      |
| 4              | 116      | 216      | 316      | 416      | 516      | 616      | 716      | 816      |
|                |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| Second Topic   |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| 1) Sub Topic-1 |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| 1              | 120      | 220      | 320      | 420      | 520      | 620      | 720      | 820      |
| 2              | 121      | 221      | 321      | 421      | 521      | 621      | 721      | 821      |
| 3              | 122      | 222      | 322      | 422      | 522      | 622      | 722      | 822      |
| 4              | 123      | 223      | 323      | 423      | 523      | 623      | 723      | 823      |
|                |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| 2) Sub Topic-2 |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| 1              | 126      | 226      | 326      | 426      | 526      | 626      | 726      | 826      |
| 2              | 127      | 227      | 327      | 427      | 527      | 627      | 727      | 827      |
| 3              | 128      | 228      | 328      | 428      | 528      | 628      | 728      | 828      |
| 4              | 129      | 229      | 329      | 429      | 529      | 629      | 729      | 829      |"""

# uniform grid of data...
df = (pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(src), sep="|", header=None).drop(columns=[0,10])
 .applymap(str.strip).replace("",np.nan).dropna(how="all").drop(1)
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .fillna(method="ffill", axis=1)
)

# first 3 rows are column names.. of which first is the main topic
df2 = df.iloc[3:].copy()
# extract topic and sub-topic from relevent rows, put onto other rows with fillna()
df2 = (df2.assign(st=df2[1].str.contains(r"^\d+\).*\-\d+$"),
          t=lambda dfa: ~dfa.st & dfa[1].str.contains("^[A-Z,a-z, ]+"),
          tk=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa.t, dfa[1], np.nan),
          stk=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa.st, dfa[1], np.nan))
 .fillna(method="ffill")
)

# remove rows that contained topic & sub-topic, plus working columns
# topic & sub-topic are part of the index
df2 = df2.drop(df2.loc[df2.t | df2.st].index).drop(columns=["t","st"]).set_index(["tk","stk"])
# back to first 3 rows are column names, 1st being main topic
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.iloc[0:3].values, names=["topic","col","sub-col"])
# move SR No into index, then stack first level of column multi-index into row index
# cleanup order of items in the index
df2 = df2.set_index(df2.columns[0], append=True).stack(0).reorder_levels([3,0,1,2])

# cleanup index name
df2.reindex(df2.index.set_names("SR No",level=3))
```

#### output

```
col                                          column 1                            column 2                           
sub-col                                      sub-col1 sub-col2 sub-col3 sub-col4 sub-col1 sub-col2 sub-col3 sub-col4
topic      tk           stk            SR No                                                                        
Main Topic First Topic  1) Sub Topic-1 1          107      207      307      407      507      607      707      807
                                       2          108      208      308      408      508      608      708      808
                                       3          109      209      309      409      509      609      709      809
                                       4          110      210      310      410      510      610      710      810
                        2) Sub Topic-2 1          113      213      313      413      513      613      713      813
                                       2          114      214      314      414      514      614      714      814
                                       3          115      215      315      415      515      615      715      815
                                       4          116      216      316      416      516      616      716      816
           Second Topic 1) Sub Topic-1 1          120      220      320      420      520      620      720      820
                                       2          121      221      321      421      521      621      721      821
                                       3          122      222      322      422      522      622      722      822
                                       4          123      223      323      423      523      623      723      823
                        2) Sub Topic-2 1          126      226      326      426      526      626      726      826
                                       2          127      227      327      427      527      627      727      827
                                       3          128      228      328      428      528      628      728      828
                                       4          129      229      329      429      529      629      729      829
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm getting following error: **NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time**. Could you help me with that?

Comment: what version of pandas?  `pd.__version__`. does it error with sample data and solution I provided or just your data?  If you data,  provide data in question as text not images

Comment: @RabRaymond I'm using "1.2.3"  version. I'm using same data and your code the sole change is I'm reading through excel and yet getting the error

Comment: I don't have excel... after `df = pd.read_excel()` can you provide data from `df.to_dict(orient="list")`   There will be something different about the DF to the one I simulated

Comment: Sure. I couldn't paste it here since, I was in shortage of characters. So, here's link: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BAd8BehD-vL0uYVj-PAu5zNL1spZ1uGB/view?usp=sharing"